# I'm having issues setting selected in dropdown with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, selectedvalue

See example [here](http://utsarotaract.org/officers.php). Clicking `[Email Me]` in the President's header should open up the contact form with `Webmaster` selected from the dropdown, but that's not happening.

I know it should be trivial, but it's not turning out that way. `get` stuff in `email()` is working alright but when it gets to the selecting an `option`, the code craps out. All relevant code is below.

My HTML:

```
<form method="get">
    <select name="to" id="to-field">
      <option name="President" value="President">President</option>
      <option name="Webmaster" value="Webmaster">Webmaster</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

My JS/jQuery:

```
function email(to){
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $.get('/inc/email.php', 
               function(data){
                    $('#email-form').html(data);
                    $('#email-form form').submit( function(){
                        var d = $('#email-form form').serialize();
                        $.ajax({
                          type:     'GET',  
                          url:      '/inc/email.php?submit=true&'+d,
                          success:  function(data) {
                                        $('#email-form').html(data);
                          }
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
            }
         );
     });

    if(to !== undefined){
        $('select#to-field').val(to);
        console.log( 'item selected -> ' + $('select#to-field').val() );
    }
}
```

This is being triggered by:

```
<span onclick="javascript:email('Webmaster');">[Email Me]</span>
```

And `console.log()` is returning:

```
item selected -> undefined
```

I've also tried setting selected using this:

```
$("select#to-field[value=" + to + "]").attr("selected","selected");
```

And even this for good measure:

```
$("select#to-field[value=" + to + "]").attr("selected",true);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code works perfectly when I tested it. Tell me, where is <span onclick="javascript:email('Webmaster');">[Email Me]</span> - is it on the same page as the form?

Comment: can you post all code in one file. So we don't have to guess.

Comment: Let me throw together a jsfiddle real quick.

Comment: Actually, with all the gets and stuff it's easier to just link to the page. [Here](http://utsarotaract.org/officers.php) is the non-working example. The [email me] on the president's header should open up the contact form with Webmaster selected, but it's not.

Comment: I'm thinking it might have to do with the AJAX load, but I'm not sure how to test for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $.get is an async event!! As it is, your

```
if(to !== undefined){
        $('select#to-field').val(to);
        console.log( 'item selected -> ' + $('select#to-field').val() );
    }
```

will execute before the inner email page is even finished loading! Put that part  *inside* your $.get callback to be done after the email page is loaded!

Put it between like this

```
$('#email-form').html(data);
//RIGHT HERE
    if(to !== undefined){
            $('select#to-field').val(to);
            console.log( 'item selected -> ' + $('select#to-field').val() );
        } 
//
$('#email-form form').submit( function(){...
```

Comment: I tried that before and when I do this nothing happens. `console.log` doesn't fire and no selection is made.

Comment: FYI, I've got the code as you suggested right now if you want to see it not working.

Comment: See my redone comment, I ment the $.get. Sorry, your success callback is after the Email submits! No, it's to be done after the $.get, not after the ajax success

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks a million!